# How to choose the nth element

Tags: automated-testing, java

Do not swear strongly if such a question has already been, but I searched and came across this solution:

```
List<WebElement> list1 =  (List<WebElement>) d.findElements(by.classname("item-list-entry ng-scope")); 
list1.get(2).click();
```

I write to Java, and I try to parse the list, go through it and click on the 3rd element.
Unfortunately, it does not help me.

The structure of my html

```
<div id="search-results" class="row search-result">
<div class="col-sm-12 col-wog">
<div class="item-list-entry ng-scope" ng-if="currentSearchOptions.display =='item-list'">
<div class="row ng-scope" ng-repeat="entry in searchResults">ITEM 1 </div>
<div class="row ng-scope" ng-repeat="entry in searchResults">ITEM 2 </div>
<div class="row ng-scope" ng-repeat="entry in searchResults">ITEM 3</div>
<div class="row ng-scope" ng-repeat="entry in searchResults">ITEM 4 </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I need the 3rd item. My decision before was simple (xpath)

```
//*[@id="search-results"]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]/p
```

Comment: What is your question? Why doesn't the xpath work anymore?

Comment: How do I choose the 3rd container div? Xpath  doesn't click on it anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the html you provided, I see no `p` so your xpath can't work, using the p.
In the code you provide, you use `By.classname`. This kind of selector works only with a single class: the class of the element you try to select, you shouldn't chain classes like this "item-list-entry ng-scope".
You can try the following Xpath:

```
 //*[@id="search-results"]//div[contains(@class,'item-list-entry')]/div[3]
```

Or you can use css selector:

```
#search-results .item-list-entry div:nth-child(3)
```

You seem to be using Java?

```
WebElement el =  d.findElement(By.cssSelector("#search-results .item-list-entry div:nth-child(3)")); 
el.click();
```

Comment: Today it worked. Thank. Leave this way)